# I have an arraylist of objects that I pass to thymeleaf gets per character instead of per element in the array

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, thymeleaf

So my code in completing the arraylist of objects from the backend is:

```
Object cat = new Object();
    List<Object> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
    double totalOrders = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<customerOrderList.size(); i++){
        Object[] row = (Object[]) customerOrderList.get(i);

        List<Object> sRow = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> pRow = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!cat.equals(row[1])){
           cat = row[1];
           outputList.add(row[0]);
           outputList.add(row[1]);
            
        } 

        pRow.add(row[2]);
        pRow.add(row[3]);
        pRow.add(row[4]);
        pRow.add(row[5]);
        pRow.add(row[6]);
        pRow.add(row[7]);

        outputList.add(pRow);
        totalOrders += new Double (row[7].toString());

    }

    model.addAttribute("soaList", outputList);
```

and on the Thymeleaf page I want to access each element on the arraylist and the arraylist looks like this:

```
[3, Fruits, [Strawberry, 1, 1kg, 2, 3, 6], 15, Others, [Cocoa Powder, 1, 500g, 19, 2, 38], 4, Vegetables, [Tomato, 1, 1kg, 1, 2, 2], [String Beans, 1, 1kg, 11, 1, 11]]
```

On the Thymeleaf, I do this:

```
<div class="report-row-content" th:each="element : ${list}">
    <th:block th:if="${element.class.name == 'java.lang.String'}">
         <div class="list-report-body-label" th:id="'cat_' + ${element[0]}" th:text="${element[1]}"></div>
    </th:block>

    <th:block th:if="${element.class.name == 'java.util.ArrayList'}">  
       <div th:classappend="('cat_' + ${element[0]}) + ' product_' + ${element[2][1]" th:text="${element[2][0]}" style="padding-left: 10px;"></div>
       <div th:text="${element[2][2]}"></div>
       <div th:text="${element[2][3]}"></div>
       <div th:text="${element[2][4]}"></div>
       <div th:text="${element[2][5]}"></div>
    </th:block>
  </div>
```

But what I get as an output on the page for element[1] is:

```
Item: e
```

instead of:

```
Item: Beef
```

I thought I was getting each element on the arraylist but it counts as per character index instead. How do I do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: 'element' itself is an item in the list, so you should just use element, or index the list instead of indexing element. And I would suggest use an objects instead of heterogenous lists. That will make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Use `List<List<Object>> outputList` is better I think

Comment: You have _parallel lists_; your code will be much cleaner, easier to understand, and easier to maintain after you create a class to represent each record.

Comment: @darshanz I think I got what you meant, thanks for this! I've got an idea on what to do next.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks it's showing an error when I did this.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I tried making a separate class for this before, but spring boot seems to require every class to be an entity and I don't want to have another table in my database for this. Or maybe I was just doing it wrong

Comment: Every class most definitely does not have to be an entity (although in your case these classes probably _are_, but you may not be familiar yet with what makes something an entity or a value). It seems like perhaps some general Java familiarity might be helpful to you.